# Convert php date to objective-c

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to find the time interval since last move in a game. Normally, in objective-c, I do this and it works great:

```
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date]; 
    NSDate *before = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:-60 sinceDate:now]; 

    NSTimeInterval interval = [now timeIntervalSinceDate: before];
```

I store the lastTurn date in mysql database:

```
timestamp   -   ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

When I try to get the date in objective-c, it seems to work:

```
    NSDate *lastTurn = match.lastTurn; 
    NSLog(@"lastTurn: %@", lastTurn);

    Output: lastTurn: 2012-03-21 09:40:32
```

...however, when I try to do a time interval, I get the -[__NSCFString timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance error.

```
    NSDate *lastTurn = match.lastTurn; 
    NSTimeInterval interval = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate: lastTurn];
```

Any suggestions would awesome. Thanks

**EDIT**

I use ASIHTTPRequest to get the information from the database to the iphone.

The Match class is just a simple class that holds the variables:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *lastTurn; 
etc...
```

... And I get the variable by doing this:

```
    [request setCompletionBlock:^
    {

     for (NSDictionary *dict in responseDict)
     {                
             Match *match = [[Match alloc] init];  
             match.lastTurn = [dict objectForKey:@"lastTurn"];
```

Comment: Can you please mention, source date(Php date) format?

Comment: Can you post the interface of your `Match` object, and the code where you build your Match objects from the sql query results ?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I edit my question with some more info :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(disclaimer: I know nothing about objective-c, so this might be complete rubbish, only reading the documentation leads to dangerous superficial knowledge ;-))

My bets are on

```
NSDate *lastTurn = match.lastTurn;
NSLog(@"className of lastTurn is %@", [lastTurn className]);
```

prints `className of lastTurn is __NSCFString` and you have to convert that string into an instance of NSDate via e.g. [dateWithString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDate/dateWithString:) before using it like an instance of NSDate.

---

[NSDate Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says:

> The sole primitive method of NSDate, [timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate), provides the basis for all the other methods in the NSDate interface.

Which means that `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` is called on both `[NSDate date]` and `lastTurn`.
The error message `-[__NSCFString timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]` states (if I'm not mistaken) that the selector `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` has been sent to an instance of `__NSCFString`, i.e. a "flavour" of NSString, not an instance of NSDate.
Since `[NSDate date]` *is* most likely an instance of NSDate there's only `lastTurn` left.

My guess is that all entries in `responseDict` are strings and a simple `NSDate *lastTurn = match.lastTurn;` doesn't do any conversion, not even (duck-)type-checking.

Comment: Great. You're right. It was a string... When converted the string to nsdate it worked (dateFromString). Thanks a ton :)